# How to display images from an API with Angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I would like to display an image which is stored in an API using Angular 10, my question is do I need to do a special method to do this ?

what is the easiest possible way to do this ?
I read we're talking about blob, isn't there a much easier way?

**Service**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BookList } from '../interfaces/book-list';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookListService {

  url: string = 'http://henri-potier.xebia.fr/books';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBookInfos(): Observable<BookList> {
    return this.http.get<BookList>(this.url);
  }
}
```

**interface**

```
export interface BookList {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    img?: string
    synopsis: string;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let user of bookList">
        <img [src]="{{user.cover}}.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="livres">
        <h1>{{user.title}}</h1>
        <p class="price">{{user.price}}</p>
        <p>{{user.synopsis}}</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ts.file**

```
bookList: any = [];

  constructor(private bookListService: BookListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookListService.getBookInfos().subscribe(data => {
      this.bookList = data });
  }
```

Comment: what is the type of image? a blob?

Comment: `<img [src]="user.cover" style="width: 100%;" alt="livres">` since the API returns a link in the `cover` field you can just do this to render ithe images. You could also use a `DomSanitizer` to secure the loading of those images.

Comment: looks like the api is just returning a url on the `cover` property. Looks like your Booklist interface has a mismatched property, `url` should be `cover`

Comment: @joshvito i need to change img?: string => cover: URL

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it

1. Save the image in AWS S3
2. create an API which will point to that image
3. now from UI you should just call that API which gives you a path to that specific location
4. On UI you can directly point to that path and show the image from the image tag

Answer (score 0):

your posted interface doesn't match the contract coming from the API you listed. It should be:

```
export interface BookList {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    cover: string 
    synopsis: string;
}
```

The above, along with the answer provided by @ Jacopo Sciampi in the comments should fix your issue.